# How competitive is it to get Google Cloud Platform credits for research?

Tags: funding, computer-science, research-proposal, code

The Google Cloud Platform (GCP) offers cloud credits for PhD students who submit a research proposal through their website:

https://edu.google.com/programs/credits

Does anybody know how competitive this competition is?

Comment: Competitive in what sense, exactly?

Comment: @Buffy competitive in the sense of how difficult is it to get? Is the selection committee highly selective when reviewing and choosing applications to give credits? Relative to the number of applications received, do a large proportion or small proportion of applicants receive the credits (i.e. is there a relatively high acceptance rate or a relatively large rejection rate)? I could not find any information like this so I posed this question hoping that someone with more knowledge and experience could help.